# Return true if ArrayList contains duplicates? And then return duplicate card?

Tags: java, eclipse, object, arraylist, return

```
// Return true if there is a duplicate card in the pack
public boolean hasDuplicate() {
    ArrayList<Card> nondoop = new ArrayList<Card>();        
    for (Card c : pack) {
        if (nondoop.contains(c)) {
            return true;
        }
        nondoop.add(c);
    }       
    return false;       
}
```

Here is my Java code, which I don't understand why it doesn't work? It always return false.  Basically this methods needs to return true if a pack of cards (a pack contains ten cards, each card created randomly (each card object has a field for the card number and suit it belongs to), hence there is a possibility for duplicate cards).

Furthermore, i am writing a method that returns the duplicate card, but must complete this first.

Comment: Did you override `equals` and `hashCode()` in `Card` ??

Comment: You have an empty new list created in this method, so when it's empty it doesn't contain anything and returns false.

Comment: @wawek but he adds `c` to the list if it's not in there...

Comment: Oh ok right, didn't notice that.

Comment: How you constract your `pack` object?

Comment: Just debug it. Did you check that the pack contains any objects???

Answer (score 4):

```
 if (nondoop.contains(c)) {
```

This checks if the object referenced by c is contained in the ArrayList. If your pack only contains distinct Card objects, your method will never return true.

The question is, what do you consider duplicate cards? Your code works if you have one Card object in a pack several times, but not if you have different Card objects with the same content (that are supposed to be equal).

Edit: if you want to prevent different Card objects that represent the same card from getting into the ArrayList, you can override the `equals()` method (and `hashCode()`) in Card to make your code work.

Comment: equals and hashCode() to don't break the contract!!

Comment: Yes, that would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

First and most important thing you have to define when a `Card` instance is equals to other instance so in your Card class you should override `equals()` and to don't break the contract `hashCode()` too.

Second you want to return the duplicates, you are returning a `boolean` value instead, so there you don't know the duplicates .

Third I would prefer to make this a static method in an util class cause you can use with what you want.

So change your code to something like.

```
public static <T> Collection<T> getDuplicates(List<T> list){
      Set<T> toAdd = new HashSet<>();
      Set<T> duplicates = new HashSet<>();

      for(T t : list){
          if(!toAdd.add(t)){
              duplicates.add(t);
          }
      }

       return duplicates;
}
```

Note that order is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for returning duplicates:

```
public Card getDuplicate() {
    int pos = 0;
    boolean has = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < pack.size(); i++) {
        for (int i1 = i+1; i1 < pack.size(); i1++) {
            if (pack.get(i).getNumber() == pack.get(i1).getNumber() && pack.get(i).getSuit() == pack.get(i1).getSuit()) {
                pos= i ;
                has = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (has == true) {
        return pack.get(pos);
    } else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Expanding on what was already said, here is a possible function signature you can use:

/** Return true if there are any duplicate cards (the same rank and suite) in the desk of cards */
public boolean hasDuplicate(List < Card >       cards) {
}
Note you can still pass into as an argument an ArrayList < Card > because ArrayList implements List. However, you can now pass in any java collection that implements List.

Comment: How this answer, answers his question?